# Enum if-else Comparisons

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums

How can I perform the proper comparison check in the following code?

```
enum Location {
    case ontop
    case inside
    case underneath
}

struct Item {
    var location: Location?

    func checkStuff(currentLocation: Location?) {
        if case .ontop = currentLocation {
            // DO SOME STUFF
        }
    }
}

// currentLocation is optional, and initially nil
var currentLocation: Location?

var item1 = Item(location: .ontop)
item1.checkStuff(currentLocation: currentLocation)

currentLocation = item1.location

var item2 = Item(location: .inside)
item2.checkStuff(currentLocation: currentLocation)
```

So there is a struct, which 1 of its properties is an enum `Location` so that it can only have 1 of 3 values.

The struct has a method that takes action if an instance's `location` property is the same as an externally provided value of the same type that is the current status of the Location (from another instance of the same object type).

I cannot get the correct syntax to get into the right section of the `if` statement.

I have also tried unwrapping the optional `currentLocation`:

```
if let tempCurrentLocation = currentLocation {
     if case tempCurrentLocation = Location.ontop {
          print("Currently ontop")
          location = .ontop
     } else {
          print("Currently NOT ontop")
          location = .inside
     }
} else {
     print("Not able to unwrap enum...")
}
```

Comment: just `switch` your enumeration location

Comment: Out of curiosity, you offer your attempt at unwrapping. While that's unnecessary, it should work. Should we infer from your comment that it didn't work for some reason? Personally, if I were to use `if case` I think that `if case tempCurrentLocation = Location.ontop { ... }` is confusing and I'd do `if case .ontop = tempCurrentLocation { ... }` instead, but your construct would appear to work. Regardless, as discussed below, there are more elegant patterns that don't require this unwrapping step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to note that `currentLocation` is not a `Location`, it's a `Location?` (a.k.a. `Optional<Location>`). So you have to pattern match against the cases of `Optional` first, not of `Location`. Then, within the patterns of `Optional`'s cases, you can match against the various cases of `Location`.

Here is the progression of syntactic sugar, starting with the most verbose, and arriving at the most succinct, common way of doing this:

- `if case Optional.some(.ontop) = currentLocation { ... }`
- `if case .some(.ontop) = currentLocation { ... }`
- And finally, the preferred way: `if case .ontop? = currentLocation { ... }`

`if case` is only really ideal if you want to check for a very small subset of a large set of cases. If you need to check multiple cases, it's better to use a `switch`. The case patterns are the same:

```
switch currentLocation {
    case .onTop?: // ...
    case .inside?: // ...
    case .underneath?: // ...
    case nil: // ...
}
```

Comment: It might be relevant that, while they're useful for the explanation, the `Optional.some(.foo)` and `.some(.foo)` patterns are rarely used, with developers preferring to use `.foo?` in almost all cases.

Comment: Yeah, i'll emphasize that.

Comment: @Rob Yeah good point. I was trying to show the direct issue with the case syntax OP was trying.

Comment: .@Alexander thanks for both the answer and its explanation - I have used your `if case .ontop? = ...` syntax and it works as expected. @Rob thanks also for your pointer as well - it looks so simple, I can't believe I haven't tried that! I will retest this as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could write it gracefully like this, it is better to use `switch` statements instead of `if` conditions.

```
enum Location {
    case ontop
    case inside
    case underneath
}

struct Item {
    var location: Location?

    func checkStuff(currentLocation: Location?) {
        switch currentLocation {
        case .ontop?:
            print("on top")
        case .inside?:
            print("inside")
        case .underneath?:
            print("underneath")

        case .none:
            print("Location is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to match the optional in the `switch` directly. That way, you handle `nil` in the same place as every other case

Comment: .@Biju thanks for the reply. This is a good structure. I expect I would use a `switch` regularly when checking. In this particular case however, I am only checking if this property is set to 1 of the available values (`.ontop`). .@Alexander, thanks again for the reminder about the `Optional`

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `switch` statement:

```
switch self.currentLocation {
case .ontop?:
    break
case .inside?:
    break
case .underneath?:
    break
case nil:
    // In this case, `self.currentLocation` is `nil` rather than one of the cases of `Location`
    break
}
```

You need to have a `?` after each of the cases in the switch statement, because `self.currentLocation` is a `Location?`. The values in the switch cases have to match the type of `self.currentLocation`. By writing simply `.ontop`, `.inside`, etc., they would be of type `Location`, whereas writing `.ontop?`, `.inside?`, etc., makes their type `Location?`, which is the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single `if` test with your `Location?` parameter, you can either add a `?`:

```
func checkStuff(currentLocation: Location?) {
    if case .ontop? = currentLocation {
        // DO SOME STUFF
    }
}
```

Or just use `==` test (which can be used to compare an optional to a literal):

```
func checkStuff(currentLocation: Location?) {
    if currentLocation == .ontop {
        // DO SOME STUFF
    }
}
```

I think this latter approach leads to more natural looking code, but the `if case` approach is really valuable if your enum had associated values (which it doesn't).

Clearly, if you wanted tests for the other `Location` enum possibilities, then you'd use `switch` statement (again with `?` after the various cases), as suggested by others:

```
func checkStuff(currentLocation: Location?) {
    switch currentLocation {
    case .ontop?:
        // DO SOME STUFF IF ONTOP
    case .inside?:
        // DO SOME OTHER STUFF IF INSIDE
    case .underneath?:
        // DO YET SOME OTHER STUFF IF UNDERNEATH
    case nil:
        // DO YET SOME OTHER STUFF IF NIL
    }
}
```